# When using StopWatch and TimeSpan how can i get hours minutes and seconds without numbers after the point?

Tags: c#, .net

I have two global vars:

```
private Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
public static TimeSpan time = new TimeSpan();
```

Then i start the stopwatch in a button click and in another button click i stop it and doing:

```
stopwatch.Stop();
time = stopwatch.Elapsed;
```

Then in form1:

```
return testclass.time;
```

The problem is in time i'm getting 00:00:00 format but for example in second i'm getting: 00:00:05.434455 i didn't check the minutes yet and hours but how can i make the format 00:00:00 that it will not have digits/numbers after the point in hours minutes and seconds ?

So what i want to get in time is for example: 00:00:05 or 12:23:12 or 09:04:01
Complete numbers without the digits after the point.

This is the full code in a new class:

```
public static TimeSpan time = new TimeSpan();
 private Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

        private void videosInsertRequest_ResponseReceived(Video obj)
        {
            uploadstatus = obj.Status.UploadStatus;
            if (uploadstatus == "uploaded")
            {
                stopwatch.Stop();
                var milliseconds = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
                time = stopwatch.Elapsed;
                uploadstatus = "file uploaded successfully";
            }
            if (uploadstatus == "Completed")
            {

            }
        }

        private void videosInsertRequest_ProgressChanged(IUploadProgress obj)
        {
            stringProgressReport[1] = obj.Status.ToString();
            if (stringProgressReport[1] == "Uploading")
            {
                stopwatch.Start();
                uploadstatus = "uploading file";
            }
        }
```

In the second event i start the StopWatch in the upper event i stop the StopWatch and assign to time the Elapsed property of the stopwatch.

Then in form1:

```
public string SendResponse(HttpListenerRequest request)
        {
            string result = "";
            string key = request.QueryString.GetKey(0);
            if (key == "cmd")
            {
                if (request.QueryString[0] == "uploadstatus")
                {
                    switch (Youtube_Uploader.uploadstatus)
                    {
                        case "file uploaded successfully":
                            Youtube_Uploader.uploadstatus = "";
                            return "upload completed," + Youtube_Uploader.fileuploadpercentages + ","
                               + test.time;
                   }
               }
             }
         }
```

Then in form1 i return the time variable as part of a string.
And then in other place in my program i'm using the time variable.

The problem is as i described above with the result i'm getting in time.

```
if (textforspeech.contains("upload completed"))
                                {
                                    String[] parts = textforspeech.split(",");
                                    String varr = parts[0];
                                    String varr1 = parts[1];
                                    String varr2 = parts[2];
```

In varr2 i'm getting the time "00:00:00"
The problem is if it's not 00:00:00 but 00:00:05.54545
I want to remove the digits after the point 54545 so i will get in varr2 only "00:00:05"

Or of it's the hours then "12:04:05" or any other case but with complete numbers without the digits after the point.

Comment: please show your full code.

Answer (score 2):

Just use Tostring method with format.
Such as 
time.ToString(@"hh:mm:ss")

Output will be like this: 00:00:05

For details check https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
time = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Round(time.TotalSeconds));
```

Comment: @HarimAbdu Hours and minutes are always whole numbers.