# Timer returning unwanted formatting

Tags: c#, timer, countdowntimer

I created a timer that returns the decreasing time:

```
public static void timerIdle_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        

    if (tempo >= 60)
    {
        minuto = tempo / 60;
        segundo = tempo % 60;
    }
    else
    {
        minuto = 0;
        segundo = tempo;
    }

    segundo--;
    if (minuto > 0)
    {
        if (segundo < 0)
        {
            segundo = 59;
            minuto--;
        }
    }

    if (minuto == 0 && segundo == 0)
    {
        timerIdle.Stop();
        timerIdle.Dispose();
        dgView.addLinha(2, "config_Teste", "TIMER ACABOU", 0);

    }
    else
    {
        tempo = (minuto * 60) + segundo;

        string temp = minuto + ":" + segundo;
        lblIdle.Text = temp;
        dgView.addLinha(2, "config_Teste", temp, 0);
    }
}
```

I get the following result:

```
...
1:12
1:11
1:10
1:9
1:8
...
0:0
```

I need to add 0 (Zero) if the minute and second has only one digit:

```
01:12
01:11
01:10
01:09
01:08
...
00:00
```

The **PadLeft()** function does not work because I am using C # 7.3 (.NET Framework 4.7.2).

Please, help-me.

Comment: Look at the `int.ToString(string)` overload and how int format strings work https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tostring. you may also want to look at C# *interpolated strings* work, and how they can use the same format strings

Comment: Timers written this way are typically inaccurate over longer periods of time.  You should instead compute a "target" DateTime in the future, by adding your desired countdown duration to DateTime.Now.  From the Tick() event, you can subtract DateTime.Now from your target time to see how much time is left.  This will be accurate no matter what the Interval on your timer is.  Additionally, you can call ToString() against the resulting TimeSpan (from the subtraction earlier), and pass in your desired format.

Comment: See marked duplicate for a literal answer to your question. That said, the comment from @Idle is correct: you should be managing the timer different, using `DateTime` and `TimeSpan` objects. Using the proper objects, you also (in addition to simply being more accurate when done correctly) have access to more relevant formatting options, such as `"hh:mm:ss"` as a format string. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32610963/when-using-stopwatch-and-timespan-how-can-i-get-hours-minutes-and-seconds-withou

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So this will format your minutes and seconds into two digits

```
int minuto = 1;
int segundo= 1;
string temp = string.Format($"{minuto:D2}:{segundo:D2}");
```

**Output:**

```
01:01
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to set the countdown duration in seconds when you start the `Timer`, subtract 1 every second in the `Tick` event until you get 0 then stop the timer. Use the [TimeSpan.FromSeconds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.fromseconds?view=netcore-3.1) method to format the time string.

```cs
//Class variable...
int segundo = 0;

void WhereYouStartTheTimer()
{
    segundo = 60; //1 Minute
    timerIdle.Interval = 1000; //Fires every 1 second.
    timerIdle.Start();
}

private void timerIdle_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    segundo--;

    if (segundo == 0)
    {
        timerIdle.Stop();
        dgView.addLinha(2, "config_Teste", "TIMER ACABOU", 0);
    }
    else
        dgView.addLinha(2, "config_Teste", TimeSpan.FromSeconds(segundo).ToString(@"mm\:ss"), 0);
}
```

Side note, you don't need to `timerIdle.Dispose();` if you create it by the designer. If you create it and subscribe to the `Tick` event by code, then you have to remove the handler too then dispose it:

```cs
//...
timerIdle.Stop();
timerIdle.Tick -= timerIdle_Tick;
timerIdle.Dispose();
//...
```

You might want to read [Standard TimeSpan format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-timespan-format-strings) for more.